# How to pass pipeline user name and access token in Dockerfile to access package

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, azure-devops, python-poetry

I have a repo which contains the Dockerfile. My task is to create the pipeline and publish the Docker to ECR but I am unable to do that as Docker build is failing. Following are details.

I have the following Dockerfile which executes successfully when I run it manually from my machine and docker image created successfully.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

ENV POETRY_HOME=/poetry

RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -

ENV PATH="/poetry/bin:${PATH}"

RUN poetry --version

WORKDIR /var/task

COPY pyproject.toml ./
COPY poetry.lock ./

RUN poetry config repositories.azure https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/xyz/_packaging/xyz-pypi/pypi/simple/

RUN poetry config http-basic.azure user.name [redacted PAT]

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
&& poetry install

COPY ./src2 .

CMD ["main.handler"]
```

But when I run the same Dockerfile using pipeline then it throws following error.

> 403 Client Error: The requested operation is not allowed. for url:

Following is my pipeline code to build Dockerfile.

```
- task: Docker@2
displayName: "Docker Build"
inputs:
 command: 'build'
 Dockerfile: '${{parameters.dockerfile}}'
 repository: '$(ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(REGION_NAME).amazonaws.com/$(ecrRepositoryName)'
 buildContext: '${{parameters.build_context}}'
 tags: |
     $(serviceName)-$(stage)-$(Build.SourceVersion)-$(Build.BuildId)
```

**Problem:**
I have found $(System.AccessToken) can be passed for access token from pipeline but how **user name** can be passed as pipeline is not manually triggered. How can I sort the issue?

Comment: You don't need a username when using a PAT. Any value will work. Did you look at the `poetry` documentation? I'm not familiar with that particular tool but presumably the docs can offer some guidance here.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Daniel Mann, I will try it again. @halfer: That key was not correct one, I manually entered some random alphabets. :)